# Censoring or Measurement Error?

Tags: measurement-error, censoring

I have a satellite-recorded variable $X_{it}$ that is supposed to act as a proxy for some socio-economic variable $Y_{it}$. However, due to limitations of the recording device, $X_{it}$ is censored both at the bottom and at the top of its range (or both left and right). So there is still variation in the low and top range of $Y_{it}$ observations where $X_{it}$ observations just take on a constant value.
What I am wondering about is:
1.) It seems to me that a problem of this kind could be equally written as a censoring and as a measurement error model. What is the reason for choosing one over the other?
2.) Suppose I regress $Y_{it}$ on $X_{it}$ in a linear model. Can I somehow make use of my knowledge where $X_{it}$ systematically misreports $Y_{it}$ to assess potential bias or strengthen the correlation?